# Grouping query for mongo and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper, database

I have a table of traces with following structure
 `id | country_iso | object_id | created_at`
 Each object can have many entries for one or more country. I need to figure out how many objects are now in each country.
 I can't just group it by country_iso, because in this case I'll get number of entries for each country, but not number of objects.
 I can't group it by country_iso and object_id, because in this time I'll get number of entries for each object in each country.

So, seems I have to get last entry for each object and then group them by country and get quantity. Also I need to avoid cases when last entry has country_iso equal to null. So if last entry for object is null, we have to get entry before last and so one ( so, the latest with not null country_iso ).

Example:

```
1 | US   | 1 | 25.02.02  
2 | null | 1 | 26.02.02  
3 | UK   | 2 | 25.02.02  
4 | UK   | 3 | 25.02.02  
5 | UK   | 4 | 25.02.02  
6 | US   | 4 | 26.02.02  `
```

Result will be

```
US | 2  
UK | 2
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas.
P.S.: Note that there's a lot of data( more than 100 000 of objects and more than 10 entries for each) and it's on remote server. So, I can't get data and somehow recalculate them using ruby on main server.

Comment: 100,000? You might be able to do that in Ruby if you need to do it often...!

Comment: I have to do it once (at least it was requested as once-only data pull)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a map-reduce, or the shorter group version.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group

http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#group-instance_method

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/collection.rb

Here's a shot at the code:

```
MyModel.collection.group(
  :key      => :country_iso
  :initial  => { :object_id_set => {} },
  :reduce   => 'function (obj,prev) { prev.object_id_set[obj.object_id] = 1; }',
  :finalize => 'function (final)    { final.object_count = keys(final.object_id_set).length }'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyCollection.where(country_iso: "US").count
```

Answer (score 0):

A less clever way is to abuse `distinct`...

```
counts = MyModel.distinct(:country_iso).map do |country_iso|
  count = MyModel.where(:country_iso => country_iso).distinct(:object_id).count
  [country_iso, count]
end
```

...though that's 1 query per country. May not be horrid @ 1ms per query.

Comment: Interesting thought, thanks. But seems it's not very good because in this case some object could appear in selections for each country. For my example it would be `US => 2, null => 1, UK => 3 `